# Merging tags materialize and materialize-css

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

The two tags [materialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/materialize) and [materializecss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/materializecss) both have the same description and refer to the same framework.

Is there a possibility to merge them?

Comment: Which tag would be the "main", official version? Or would [tag:materialize-css] be better?

Comment: @PaulRoub I would assume [tag:materialize] since that seems to be the official name. However, the domain name is materializecss.com

Comment: The official name is Materialize. (Also it's not just a CSS library but also contains significant part JavaScript)

Comment: If it has JS too you can't call it materialize. Do -css and -js if anything.

Comment: @DaniSpringer Materialize is a framework similar to Bootstrap, it includes CSS and the JS is a major supporting underlying code to allow animations, date selectors, etc.

Comment: Then materialize (IMHO)

Comment: @DaniSpringer That's what I think as well.

Comment: Where do you search tags? I wonder if Boostrap has -css -js stuff. It might help to add to the question how many posts have each tag.

Comment: @DaniSpringer tags are autocompleted in the search field. Also no, it's  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap

Comment: You get my vote :)

Comment: I'd say `materializecss` on the chance that something else called `materialize*` gets released

Comment: @MacroMan But the name of this is already Materialize. I would prefer to have the legitimate name rather than doing that.